# How to get multiple tables in Dataset from XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am reading XML inside the Dataset.Following is my XML structure.

**XML:-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <root>
       <ClaimHomePage>
           <item>
                <controlID>txtHospitalName</controlID>
                <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
                <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
          <item>
                <controlID>txtHospitalAddress</controlID>
                <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
                <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
          <item>
                <controlID>txtAuthorizeAmount</controlID>
                <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
                <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
          <item>
               <controlID>txtDtTmOfAdmission</controlID>
               <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
               <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>  
       </ClaimHomePage>
       <ClaimBillDetailHC>
          <item>
               <controlID>txtHospitalName</controlID>
               <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
               <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
          <item>
               <controlID>txtHospitalAddress</controlID>
               <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
               <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
          <item>
               <controlID>txtAuthorizeAmount</controlID>
               <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
               <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
          <item>
               <controlID>txtDtTmOfAdmission</controlID>
               <rolesEnabled>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesEnabled>
               <rolesVisible>Non Medico,Medico,Auditor,CMO</rolesVisible>
          </item>
       </ClaimBillDetailHC>
  </root>

enter code here
```

There are two root nodes inside the main root node(i.e. ClaimHomePage,ClaimBillDetailHC).
I want to write a code so that when i create Dataset from this XML,there should be two tables (i.e ClaimHomePage & ClaimBillDetailHC) present in the Dataset.
Please provide some help...

Answer (score 2):

Use `Relations` collection. I think this is the direct way to get table instance.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(file);
 if (ds.Relations.Count == 2)
  {
     DataTable first = ds.Relations[0].ChildTable;
     DataTable second = ds.Relations[0].ChildTable;

     Console.WriteLine("Table  : " + ds.Relations[0].ParentTable.TableName);
     foreach (DataRow  row in first.Rows)
       Console.WriteLine(row["controlID"] + " " + row["rolesEnabled"] + " " + row["rolesVisible"]);
 }
```

You have to read `XML` document using DOM or Linq to XML API and then after you may populate DataSet/DataTable.

For instance (Linq to XML)

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
 //List from ClaimHomePage 
 var ClaimHomePage = from ele in doc.Root.Element("ClaimHomePage").Descendants("item")
                            select new
                            {
                                 ControlID=(string)ele.Element("controlID"),
                                 rolesEnabled = (string)ele.Element("rolesEnabled"),
                                 rolesVisible = (string)ele.Element("rolesVisible"),
                            };
  var ClaimBillDetailHC= from ele in doc.Root.Element("ClaimBillDetailHC").Descendants("item")
                            select new
                            {
                                 ControlID=(string)ele.Element("controlID"),
                                 rolesEnabled = (string)ele.Element("rolesEnabled"),
                                 rolesVisible = (string)ele.Element("rolesVisible"),
                            };
```

And then traverse the lists and populate DataTable/DataSet.

Comment: I am doing the same thing you have done...but isn't there the direct way to get dataset...like .dataset.readxml()etc.

Comment: @AVD-thanks for your help...i tried your code,but both first and second tables are having all item collections,i wanted first table should have it's own item collection and so for the second.however i have solved my problem using linq...but still wonder wheather we can get multiple tables collection in one dataset through xml..