# LINQ on DataRelationCollection (DataSet.Relations)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-7.0

While working on an app that will import XML to SQL Server.
XML has a structure like in this question: [How to get multiple tables in Dataset from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783924/how-to-get-multiple-tables-in-dataset-from-xml)

I'm able to load XML into DataSet and get the correct tables using the above code:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var employees = new DataTable("Employees");
var cars = new DataTable("Cars");
//and others

using Stream stream = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
ds.ReadXml(stream);

foreach (DataRelation dataRelation in ds.Relations)
{
    switch (dataRelation.ParentTable.TableName)
    {
        case "Employees":
            employees = dataRelation.ChildTable;
            break;
        case "Cars":
            cars = dataRelation.ChildTable;
            break;
        //and others
    }
}
```

but when I try to do a similar thing with LINQ:

```
var dt1 = ds.Relations.Where(x => x.RelationName == "Employees").FirstOrDefault();
```

I get this error:

> Error CS1061  'DataRelationCollection' does not contain a definition
> for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a
> first argument of type 'DataRelationCollection' could be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is there a better way to get a specific DataTable from DataSet (by using DataRelation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataRelationCollection` implements only non-generic version of `ICollection` (inherited from [`InternalDataCollectionBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase?view=net-7.0) ) which is quite limited in terms of LINQ methods supported, you can "enable" generic methods via `OfType` call:

```cs
var dt1 = dataRelationCollection.OfType<DataRelation>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.RelationName == "Employees");
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think I could use `OfType` to "add" LINQ support